# how to sort a table from database

Tags: java, mysql, database, h2

I want to be able to sort a table from the database, according to either the quatity or the name, but how do i decided what happens in what case?

Below is the code for the table.

```
public void tableupdate(JTable jTable1, String fill) {

    try {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:file:D:/Inventory.db", "sa", "");

            Statement stat = con.createStatement();
            fill = "SELECT * FROM BOOKDESC  ";
            ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(fill);

            while (jTable1.getRowCount() > 0) {
                ((DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel()).removeRow(0);

            }
            int columns = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Object[] row = new Object[columns];
                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                    row[i - 1] = rs.getObject(i);

                }
                ((DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel()).insertRow(rs.getRow() - 1, row);

            }
            rs.close();
            stat.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

}
```

Comment: You really need sort in java?

Comment: The easy way is to add an Order By clause to your SQL statement.  The correct way is to enable sorting on the table.  There are tons of how-to's on multiple ways to accomplish this.

Comment: I think you can use an ORDER BY clause in your SQL query to make the sorting being taken cared by MySQL. No need to exhaust Java for sorting

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is offering a method for sorting data in your SELECT statement, it's called ORDER BY.

Usage is found [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/order_by.php).

This way, your code doesn't have to do the work, as your ResultSet already gets sorted data.

Comment: yes but what if i want to order by name or number then how do i decide?

Comment: I guess I need further information on how your data looks like. In general, you could add "ORDER BY field ASC / DESC" to your statement where "field" is the name of your column and "ASC/DESC" stand for ascending / descending, depending on which direction you want your data sorted.